# PHP: trying to substract the returning values from strpos()

Tags: php, string

i have this code:

```
<?php var_dump(strpos($url, "cashgold.")+9) ?>

<?php var_dump(strpos($url, '/', 8)) ?>

<?php $resta = strpos($url, '/', 8) - strpos($url, "cashgold.")+9 ?>

<?php var_dump($resta) ?>
```

this prints:

20 
22
20

I expected it prints :

20
22
2

Comment: What's in `$url` ?? Also you may want to edit you original question rather than adding an answer with edits ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're having issues with maths - specifically with [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

When you're doing

```
<?php $resta = strpos($url, '/', 8) - strpos($url, "cashgold.")+9 ?>
```

you're doing (22 - 11) + 9.  This is because + and - are the same precedence, so it's being evaluated left to right.

Try (note the brackets)

```
<?php $resta = strpos($url, '/', 8) - (strpos($url, "cashgold.")+9) ?>
```

to do the calculation you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i should write:

```
(strpos($url, "cashgold.")+9)
```